# ensuring a cancelled git filter-branch does not change any file in repo

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I recently ran the command `git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch utils.js"` in a feature branch with the aim of removing a file from my git repo/history (I did this locally and planned to push to github). However, once the command outputted `Rewrite <git hash> (123/1122) (102 seconds passed, remaining 802 predicted)` I learned that `git filter-branch` potentially can alter files without my knowledge, and thus I cancelled it with ctrl+c. No files to be committed were recorded in VSCode. I then switched to the master branch and ran `git fetch --all` and `git reset --hard origin/master`. My latest commit for master locally is the same as that on github's master, and vscode shows no files to be committed (which I take to mean no files have been changed). However, the documentation at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch states that says "git filter-branch has a plethora of pitfalls that can produce non-obvious manglings of the intended history rewrite" - is anyone able to confirm that the steps I have taken with `git fetch --all` and `git reset --hard origin/master` are enough to ensure that my files are ok, or are there other things I need to do to make sure that the `git filter-branch` command didn't change any other file in my repo?

Answer (score 0):

You should have duplicated your working tree folder before running such a dangerous command, and the docs tell you to do so, but it seems you didn't. The state of your local repo is thus in doubt. Best course of action: Throw your project away and make a new clone.

Comment: I can do this, that's fine. My latest commit that is on github is from 4 days ago, and I can performed the aforementioned actions yesterday, so there's no chance what I did (locally) will have affected anything on github right?

Comment: That's right. You never said `push` after those actions so you GitHub repo is untouched.